# Putting a javascript on a list menu

Tags: html, css

Iam trying to put +1 button on a menu i have on my site with list type

The code of +1 google button script is this

```
<!-- Τοποθετήστε αυτήν την ετικέτα εκεί που θέλετε να γίνει απόδοση του Κουμπί +1. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></div>

<!-- Τοποθετήστε αυτήν την ετικέτα μετά την τελευταία ετικέτα Κουμπί +1. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.___gcfg = {lang: 'el'};

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Unfortunately the list i already use on a menu continues with a searchbar on the end. 
So when i put the script on the list `<li> </li>` it takes all over the menu so the searchbar on the end is pulled down. doesnt anybody knows how can i restrict the +1 button only on a space??

Thanks in advance. I should tell that iam working o blogger with html/css.
If i asked the question on wrong forum please forgive me.

Comment: See if you can set this up in http://jsfiddle.net/, it will help us help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/k7z29/ . 
Iam trying to put this https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/
after the g+ icon.